# Dataflow Scio : can't get the string result as the local language

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, spotify-scio

I'new for dataflow, Scala and apache beam. I have created the dataflow to read the result from text file. And need to pass the value to the decryption function.

But, my issue is when I get the result from decryption function. it can't show the Thai language.(It present like '??') And I noticed that if I call this function before using scio. it can show correctly. I don't sure what is it the root cause and how to fix it. Can anyone please suggest. Thank you so much.

```
        val c = "AAAADCeGmijmVRjgaC6s7UCgaPP0LAhvgvq9NKZc0BaNJs+G01xGy3s="
        val msgbytes = decrypt(c).getBytes("UTF-8")
        val msg = new String(msgbytes, "UTF-8")
        println("msgbefore",msg)
        val query = sc.parallelize(uris).map{
            row => 
                val msgbytesaf = decrypt(c).getBytes("UTF-8")
                val msgaf = new String(msgbytesaf, "UTF-8")
                println("msgbefore",msg)
                println("msgafter",msgaf)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds strange. Could you provide a bit more details to reproduce: what does `decrypt` do? In order to troubleshoot, did you compare `msgbytes` and `msgbytesaf`?

Comment: Also where does the screenshot comes from? We don't see the 3 logs we should see. Could it be that logs you're showing are aggregated and one source is not using proper encoding? Meaning: can you somehow check the output as close as possible to the execution?